# About Android SDK native methods

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

There's lot of native methods defined in Android SDK's `StaticLayout.java`(which is in package `android.text`) file shown as below:

```
private static native long nNewBuilder();

...

private static native int nComputeLineBreaks(long nativePtr, LineBreaks recycle,
        int[] recycleBreaks, float[] recycleWidths, int[] recycleFlags, int recycleLength);
```

Then I start to search for those native methods [here](http://androidxref.com/),and I found those C++ codes. Take the native function `nComputeLineBreaks` for example, there's a method in `/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_text_StaticLayout.cpp` file like:

```
static jint nComputeLineBreaks(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jlong nativePtr,
    // Inputs
    jcharArray javaText,
    jlong measuredTextPtr,
    jint length,
    jfloat firstWidth,
    jint firstWidthLineCount,
    jfloat restWidth,
    jintArray variableTabStops,
    jint defaultTabStop,
    jint indentsOffset,...)
```

It seems to me that the `StaticLayout` is relying on native methods to do some heavy tasks, but what I don't understand is **how this native methods can be called**, does it mean that, for example, if we have a native method defined in Android framework like `static jint sayHello(JNIEnv* env, jclass)` can be called by my Android application directly by defining a method in my java class like `private static native int nSayHello();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because JNI is based on class, not just method name. So `nComputeLineBreaks()` can be called by `android.text.StaticLayout`, but not by other classes.

This is not unique to the framework. This is standard JNI behavior.

Comment: Do you mean that if I set my package to `android.text` and name my class as `StaticLayout.java` I will be able to call those native methods without any other setup?

Comment: @WALKER: No, since you cannot do that. Possibly, that will result in a build failure. Possibly, you will get a compiled app, and your `StaticLayout` will be ignored, with your process using the existing `StaticLayout` that is already in your virtual machine.